# Overloading (c)begin/(c)end

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, constants

I tried to overload `(c)begin`/`(c)end` functions for a class so as to be able to call C++11 range-based for loop.

It works in most of the cases, but I don't manage to understand and solve one :

```
for (auto const& point : fProjectData->getPoints()){ ... }
```

This line returns error:

```
Error C2662: 'MyCollection<T>::begin' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const MyCollection' to 'MyCollection<T> &'
```

because `fProjectData` is a pointer to const. If I make it non-const, it does work. I don't understand why, considering that `cbegin()` & `cend()` are developped with exactness as `begin()` & `end()` functions.

Here are my functions developped (in the header file) in MyCollection:

```
/// \returns the begin iterator
typename std::list<T>::iterator begin() {
    return objects.begin();
}

/// \returns the begin const iterator
typename std::list<T>::const_iterator cbegin() const {
    return objects.cbegin();
}

/// \returns the end iterator
typename std::list<T>::iterator end() {
    return objects.end();
}

/// \returns the end const iterator
typename std::list<T>::const_iterator cend() const {
    return objects.cend();
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: post MyCollection<T> code.

Comment: It seems like you forget to declare your begin and end methods const. You should declare a begin method that returns a non const iterator and a const begin method that returns a const iterator.

Comment: I also smell something funny with regards to the presence / absence of `<T>` in that error message... why is `begin()` seeing a non-templated `this`?

Comment: I've edited my post with the functions. Did I forget smtg ? thx

Comment: you probably meant to have `typename std::list<T>::const_iterator begin() const` instead of `typename std::list<T>::const_iterator cbegin() const`. range-based for loop looks up for `begin`/`end` names, not `cbegin`/`cend`, they were added for convenience (forcing const iterators)

Comment: It does work with begin() and end() constant functions. I seem wired to me that the range-based for loops only looks up with begin & end function instead of cbegin & cend, but I have no other choice than to accept it :)...
Thanks all of you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A range-based for loop (for a class-type range) looks up for `begin` and `end` functions. `cbegin` and `cend` are not considered at all:

§ 6.5.4 [stmt.ranged]/p1 *:

> [...]
>
> - if `_RangeT` is a class type, the *unqualified-ids* `begin` and `end` are looked up in the scope of class `_RangeT` as if by class member access lookup (3.4.5), and if either (or both) finds at least one declaration, *begin-expr* and *end-expr* are `__range.begin()` and `__range.end()`, respectively;
> - otherwise, *begin-expr* and *end-expr* are `begin(__range)` and `end(__range)`, respectively, where `begin` and `end` are looked up in the associated namespaces (3.4.2). [ *Note*: Ordinary unqualified lookup (3.4.1) is not performed. — *end note* ]

For a `const`-qualified range the related member functions must be `const`-qualified as well (or should be callable with a `const`-qualified instance if the latter option is in use). You'd need to introduce additional overloads:

```
typename std::list<T>::iterator begin() {
    return objects.begin();
}

typename std::list<T>::const_iterator begin() const {
//                                            ~~~~^
    return objects.begin();
}

typename std::list<T>::const_iterator cbegin() const {
    return begin();
}

typename std::list<T>::iterator end() {
    return objects.end();
}

typename std::list<T>::const_iterator end() const {
//                                          ~~~~^
    return objects.end();
}

typename std::list<T>::const_iterator cend() const {
    return end();
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a133ee1a552dad69)

---

<sub><sup>*</sup> the wording comes from C++14, but the differences are unrelated to the problem as it is stated</sub>